# Lowest values of an array if more than one result

Tags: java, arrays, search, arraylist, integer

I need to find the lowest value in an array, but I want to know how to handle multiple results. Say my array contains `[1,4,7,5,3,1]` - my result should be `1,1`. Any ideas?

```
double minimum = array1[0]; //sets the first to be the smallest
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) //goes through your array
{
 if (array1[i] < array1[0]) //checks and replaces if necessary
 {
    minimum = array[i];   

 }
}

System.out.println( minimum ); //returns the value of the smallest
```

Comment: How about you keep a counter for how many occurrences of that minimum you've seen? Also, be aware that directly comparing `double` values for equality is rarely a good idea. You might want some kind of tolerance level. Do you actually *need* to use `double` rather than `int`?

Comment: Sort the array; iterate from the beginning until the value of your current element is the same as the previous value.

Comment: Say I needed to get the index of the minimum values though? Rather than just counting the the amount of lowest values I want to store their indexes in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a small mistake in your code, you should have compare the current value to the minimum and not to the first value

```
double minimum = array1[0]; //sets the first to be the smallest
var minValueCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) //goes through your array
{
 if (array1[i] < minimum) //checks and replaces if necessary
 {
    minimum = array[i];  
    minValueCounter  = 1; 

 }
 else if (array1[i] == minimum) //checks and replaces if necessary
 {
    minValueCounter++;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing can be **"Sort"** your array in ascending order & then display values from the start till they are equal

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.sort(array1);
ArrayList<Integer> smallestValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
smallestValues.add(array1[0]);
int i=1;
while (i<array1.length && (array1[i] == array1[i-1])) {
     smallestValues.add(array1[i]);
    i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep another variable to count duplicates. If you find values that are equal to the current minimum value, increment this count. Remember to reset the count everytime the minimum changes.

Answer (score 0):

*How about using `Collections.sort()`*

i am assuming your `array1[]` is of `double` type

```
double array1[] = new double[] { 1, 4, 7, 5, 3, 1 };
ArrayList<Double> al = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
    al.add(array1[i]);
Collections.sort(al);
System.out.println(al.toString());
```

*Output:*

```
[1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0]
```

*To Print All Equal Smallest Values use*

```
for (int i = 0; i < (al.size() - 1); i++) { // why (al.size() - 1), Its better if try to learn yourself
    if (Double.compare(al.get(i), al.get(i+1))==0)
       System.out.print(""+al.get(i) + "," + al.get(i + 1));
    else
       break;
}
```

*Output:*

```
1.0,1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
    int[] a = { 1, 4, 7, 5, 3, 1 };
    Arrays.sort(a);
    int n = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length && a[i] == a[0]; i++)
        n++;
    int[] res = Arrays.copyOf(a, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, a solution without for loop:

```
    Integer[] inputA = new Integer[]{1,4,7,5,3,1};
    List<Integer> inputL = Arrays.asList(inputA);        

    Collections.sort(inputL);

    int last = Collections.frequency(inputL, Collections.min(inputL));

    inputA = Arrays.copyOfRange(inputL.toArray(new Integer[inputL.size()]), 0, last);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(inputA));
```

outputs:

```
   [1, 1]
```

relevant methods apidoc (all static):

- [Collections#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)
- [Collections#frequency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29)
- [Collections#min](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection%29)
- [Arrays#copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28int%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29)
- [Arrays#deepToString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)